# I get my Firebase user Uid but its dataSnapshot keys value return null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase Realtime Database structure

[image]

I've made two apps in a eBook project, one for the admin and the other for the users.

When admin gives input to a book's data on Firebase then the user will be able to see the information provided by admin in his app.

I did this on the user app but the admin Id still has the following key's value is null.

And when I was debugging the app, my `DataSnapshot` showed me the value null of the key.

My app debugging mode:

[when I get admin Uid but it show me null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRpwY.png)

[when I set admin id in database Reference and its get Uid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdbhW.png)

[and I'm get admin Id throw database reference but it dataSnapshot key's value is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGlYl.png)

Here is my code:

```
private String adminId;
private Button button1,button2,button3;
private RecyclerView bookListRv;
private ArrayList<Book> bookList;
private BookAdapter bookAdapter;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

public BookListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book_list, container, false);

    init(view);
    adminId = firebaseAuth.getUid();


    configRv();

    getBooks();


    return view;
}



private void init(View view) {

    bookListRv = view.findViewById(R.id.bookRVId);
    firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth.getInstance();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    bookAdapter = new BookAdapter(bookList, getContext());
}

private void configRv() {
    bookListRv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    bookListRv.setAdapter(bookAdapter);
}

private void getBooks(){
    DatabaseReference showBookRef = databaseReference.child("Books").child(adminId);

    showBookRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Book book = data.child("BookInfo").getValue(Book.class);
                    bookList.add(book);
                    bookAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

Any help me for appreciated

Comment: The first step is to stop ignoring potential errors and implement `onCancelled`. The minimum implementation is `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Observations**:

1. In Admin app you upload `BookInfo` under admin UID - `oJ26Q...G3`
2. In User app you try to fetch this `BookInfo` using user UID - `0FX6M...`

**Conclusions**:

1. That's mean you can't access the `BookInfo` using user UID.
2. If you know the admin UID then you can access it from user app.

**Possible Solution**:
Upload the `BookInfo` in a common place [*irrespective of user*], so that every user gets access the `BookInfo` as soon as admin upload it.

Then query it like below:

```
databaseReference.child("Books").addValueEventListener
```

**Workaround in current situations**: 
You have to use the `adminId` as hardcoded to get the `BookInfo`. Check below:

```
private void getBooks(){
    DatabaseReference showBookRef = databaseReference.child("Books").child("oJ26QDoFZBWAgWjxbFOX5jv1tcG3");

    showBookRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Book book = data.child("BookInfo").getValue(Book.class);
                    bookList.add(book);
                    bookAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Md. Asaduzzaman sir, First of all I get admin uId throw `adminId = firebaseAuth.getUid();` but its debugging mode show me null and when I write this code `DatabaseReference showBookRef = databaseReference.child("Books").child(adminId);` its get admin Uid and I'm using `showBookRef.addValueEventListener` then it shows me `DataSnapshot { key = 0FX6MlEmaWNuDVcRv3HgZC8Oq8a2, value = null }`

Comment: You couldn't do that. I checked you image and found that the UID is different. Please check carefully.

Comment: Also check in your database `BookInfo` is not under this UID `0FX6MlEmaWNuDVcRv3HgZC8Oq8a2`. That is different something like `oJ26Q...G3`

Comment: @RifatKhan, Did you check?

Comment: yes sir but its not working. can you help me how can I retrieve data from this `oJ26QDoFZBWAgWjxbFOX5jv1tcG3` uId. because this is my admin uId and I retrieve data from another user uId.

Comment: Hi @RifatKhan, glad to hear that. Please also hit upvote so that others can find it helpful. Thanks